# Rotate Points on ContourPlot and ListPointPlot3D

Tags: plotting, rotation

So I have some minima of a function which I found by brute force, whose xy coordinates are given below in `coord` and their value is given in `energies`.

Because of the symmetry of the function I am minimising, I am only performing the optimisation in a region between 0 and 45 degrees.

1) In the `CountourPlot`, I am using `coords` to plot `Points` at those positions, in the `Epilog`. How can I rotate them about the origin (8 times, 45 degrees each time), so that I see the fully symmetric picture?

2) In the `ListPointPlot3D` I am plotting their value vs. xy plane, so that I can fit a Gaussian to it or something. How can I rotate the xy coordinates in the same way as above, but also such that the values at those points are carried over?

Code:

```
coords = {{0.6190336712698862`, 0}, {1.8602613403366641`, 
    1.0245504661458222`}, {2.0398699908107805`, 
    0.5909368262516823`}, {2.0624401421510528`, 
    0}, {1.456538407177356`, 0}, {1.02708081178471`, 
    0.4254308018943951`}, {1.4668764036170645`, 0.6076001007032582`}}; 

energies = {6.934067103095236`, 6.096006662217476`, 
   6.096006662217476`, 8.286935949864931`, 8.617671780484468`, 
   7.809519828670573`, 6.557138040453592`};

RealPotential[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2

ContourPlot[RealPotential[x, y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 ImageSize -> Scaled[0.3], ColorFunction -> "DarkTerrain", 
 Contours -> 15, 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], {Opacity[0], Cyan, 
    Point[coords]}, {Cyan, Point[coords]}}]

bla = Table[
   Flatten[{coords[[n]], energies[[n]]}], {n, 1, Length[energies]}];

ListPointPlot3D[bla, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> 500]
```

Comment: `RotationTransform[π/4]@coords` would be a place to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
coords2 = Join @@ NestList[RotationTransform[π/4], coords, 7]; 
ContourPlot[RealPotential[x, y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 ImageSize -> Scaled[0.3], ColorFunction -> "DarkTerrain", 
 Contours -> 15, Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Cyan, Point@coords2}]
```

[image]

```
bla2 = Join @@ (Flatten /@ Thread[{NestList[RotationTransform[π/4], {#, #2}, 7], #3}]& @@@
   bla);
ListPlot3D[bla2, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]